# Data Structure USed for Snake and Ladder game

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came across a interview question "Suggest data structures you would use for snake & ladder game? "

I would use a 2D array (same as we do in chess ) to design each block of game. But is it possible to design it in 1D array ? Many people has suggested this but no one has explained how to do it.

Comment: For easy implementation: https://codepumpkin.com/snakes-n-ladders/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rules for **Snake and Ladder** are:

1. There are two players in this game and board size is 100.(10 X 10)
2. Possible outcomes by throwing a dice are 1,2,3,4,5,6.
3. If output is 6 then current player will get a chance again to throw the Dice.
4. If outcome of the Dice is 1,2,3,4,5,6 and player positioned on mouth of snake then his current position will change to tail of snake, and he will not get other chance until he throws a dice which has value 6.
5. If outcome of the Dice is 1,2,3,4,5,6 and player positioned at below of ladder then His current position will change to topmost position of ladder and he will get another chance to throw the dice again.
6. If player's current position+ roll >100 then take the following considerations
   i. if(roll==6) current player will get the chance again ,otherwise other player will get.
7. Any player reach 100 earlier than other player will be the winner and game will end.

We are passing only one HashMap, which contains the current position as key and next position as value. I think one HashMap will complete  all the requirement of the Ladder and Snake,

```
int playSnakeAndLadder(HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap){
    int player1=1, player2=1;// Initial position of players
    int chance=0;// This value show the change of players if chance is odd then player1 will play
                 // if chance is even then player2 will play
    while(1){
        if((player1==100)||(player2==100))// if any of player's position is 100 return chance;
            return chance;// Here chance shows who win the game, if chance is even player1 wins other //wise player2 wins
    int roll=Randon(6);// this will generate random number from 1 to 6.
    if(chance%2==0){
         int key=roll+player1;// new position of player1             
         boolean isLadder=false;// This is for checking the turn current player if againTurn is ture 
         // then the current player will player again.
         if(hashMap.contains(Key)){
             player1=hashMap.getValue(Key);
             // Here player current position will automatically update according to the hashMap.
             // if there is a snake the key value is greater than it mapping value.
             // if there is a ladder then key value is less than it mapping value. 
             if(Key<hashMap.getValue(Key))
                 isLadder=true;// Here player gets ladder.
             if(isLadder==true && roll==6 || isLadder==true)
               chance=chance;
             else
               chance=(chance+1)%2;
         }
         else if(player1+roll>100 && roll!=6)
               chance=(chance+1)%2;
            else if(player1+roll>100 && roll==6)
               chance=chance;
            else if(roll==6){
               player1=player1+roll;
               chance=chance;
            }
            else{
               player1=player1+roll;
               chance1=(chance1+1)%2;
            }                 
       }


    else{// Now similarly for player2
              {
             int key=roll+player2;// new position of player2             
             boolean isLadder=false;// This is for checking the turn current player if againTurn is ture 
             // then the current player will player again.
             if(hashMap.contains(Key)){
                 player2=hashMap.getValue(Key);
                 // Here player current position will automatically update according to the hashMap.
                 // if there is snake the key value is greater than it mapping value.
                 // if there is ladder then key value is less than it mapping value. 
                 if(Key<hashMap.getValue(Key))
                     isLadder=true;// Here player gets ladder.
                 if(isLadder==true && roll==6 || isLadder==true)
                   chance=chance;
                 else
                   chance=(chance+1)%2;
             }
             else if(player2+roll>100 && roll!=6)
                   chance=(chance+1)%2;
                else if(player2+roll>100 && roll==6)
                   chance=chance;
                else if(roll==6){
                   player2=player2+roll;
                   chance=chance;
                }
                else{
                   player2=player2+roll;
                   chance=(chance+1)%2;
                }                 
        }
       }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Vakh is correct.
"Yes it is possible: every 2D array can be represented as a 1D array."

The array

```
int board[100] =
{
     0,  0,  0, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0, 22,  0,
     0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,-10,  0,  0, 18,
     0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 56,  0,  0,
     0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 19,
    17,  0,  0,-20,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
     0,-43, 18, -4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    20,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
     0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,-63,  0,  0,
     0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
     0,  0,-20,  0,-20,  0,  0,  0,-21,  0
};
```

can hold ladders
4->14, 9->13, 20->38, 28->84, 40->59, 51->67, 63->81, 71->91
and snakes
17->7, 54->34, 62->19, 64->60, 87->24, 93->73, 95->75, 99->78

if red is at position 2 (i.e. r=2) and scores 2 (i.e. s=2) then new position of red is

```
    2+2+board[2+2-1] = 14
```

i.e.

```
    r = r + s + board[r+s-1])
```

@Jan Dvorak,
"jagged arrays are not 2D array"

Answer (score 1):

In the [implementation](http://programmingpraxis.com/2011/03/04/chutes-and-ladders/) at my blog, I used a simple pair of linked lists to store the snakes and ladders. Each element of the list had a pair of squares, the "from" square and the "to" square; if you landed on any "from" square, your piece was relocated to the "to" square. I found a minimum game length of 7 turns, and an average game length of 33 turns. You could alternately use a one-dimensional array, where the index of the array indicates the "from" square and the value in the array represents the "to" square, which is the same as the index except at the beginning of a snake or ladder.

Answer (score 1):

Why no one is suggesting using Map as a data structure. We will map the integer to itself if there is no snake or ladder. In case of snake we will map the head of snake to its tail and similarly for ladder also. We can use integer variable for each player.

Answer (score 0):

Since movement in Snakes/Chutes and Ladders is usually in a single direction, rather than the multiple directions possible in Chess, a 1D array or list should definitely work.

To represent the snakes and the ladders, you could set the contents of each list element to be an integer, telling the game how far to skip your counter ahead or back when you land on it. For example, in Python:

```
# create a 5x5 board
board = [0 for i in range(25)]
# put a ladder in square 3, that moves you to square 10
board[2] = 7
# put a snake in square 14, that moves you to square 9
board[13] = -5
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible: every 2D array can be represented as a 1D array.

Represent all the rows of the 2D array one after another in a 1D array. Doing so, `2d[i][j]` becomes `1d[i * rowLength + j]`. Unless you have no other choice than using a 1d array, it is usually not a good thing to do as it becomes less readable and less easy to use.

Comment: "every 2D array can be represented as a 1D array" -- jagged arrays are difficult to represent as a single 1D array and impossible to index efficiently. Did you mean "every rectangular array"? Pedantic, I know... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using Array:

```
int SNL[100];
```

every element of this array contains an integer according to following rule:

1. if there is a ladder starting from `x` to `x+l`, then `SNL[x]=l;`
2. if there is a snake bite at `x` and leaving you at `x-s`, then `SNL[x]=-s;`, otherwise `SNL[x]=0;`

Answer (score 0):

Surely we can solve the problem using 1D array because the numbers marked on board are from 1 to 100. We can initialize two 1D arrays: snake and ladder both of 100 size. 
If the player at snake head(suppose at 56) then it have to move to its tail(suppose at 6). Then snake[56] = 6 (according to the rule) the player will move to block which is marked as 6. Similarly for the ladder array. I have covered the case in which the player is at snake head and navigated to its tail and there is found a ladder and vice versa.
The pseudo code is:

```
int snake[101], ladder[101];
void SnakeAndLadder()
{
    int player_1=1, player_2=1, turn_player_1 = 1, a;
    while(1)
    {
        a = rand()%6 +1;
        if(turn_i==1)
        {
            turn_player_1 = 0;
            player_1 = takeStep(player_1+a);
            if(player_1==100)
            {
                cout<<"Player 1 won";
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            turn_player_1 = 1;
            player_2 = takeStep(player_2+a);
            if(player_2==100)
            {
                cout<<"Player 2 won";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int takeStep(int i)
{
    if(i<100)
    {
    if(snake[i]!=0 && i!=100)
    {
        i = snake[i];
    }
    if(ladder[i]!=0 && i!=100)
    {
        i = ladder[i];
        if(snake[i]!=0 && i!=100)
        {
            i= snake[i];
        }
    }
    }
return i;
}
```